# Multer not saving file as file

Tags: node.js, multer

I have setup multer as middleware on a route. When that route is hit, multer doesn't download the file. This is what console.log reports:

```
{ firstname: 'foo',
  lastname: 'foo',
  username: 'foo10',
  password: 'test1234',
  file: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAAB.....

}
```

I have the following setup for multer:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null,  '../images/profile');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, req.body.username + '.jpeg');
  }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

router.post('/auth/signup', upload.single('file'), function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

So the issue is that instead of saving the file as a file it simply treats it as another key-value pair in the form.

To clarify further, i obtain this image from cordova API:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/camera/

```
import { Camera } from 'ionic-native';

Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64:
   let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;

   let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
        xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();     
        formData.append("file", base64Image);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                observer.complete();
            } else {
                observer.error(xhr.response);
            }
          }
        };
      xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/auth/signup', true);
      xhr.send(formData); 

}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
```

Comment: I don't get it? You are trying to save a file and it isn't working properly? what is happening?

Comment: clarification added

Comment: That looks like a Base64-encoded JPEG. Are you sure your client-side code is uploading the form data properly?

Comment: @robertklep yes.. i guess it is base64.. so what is wrong about that ?

Comment: Can you add the code that you're using to upload the data? Are you using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) or something? The Base64 suggests that you may not be adding a `File` field.

Comment: @robertklep  ..code I am utilizing to transmit is added up. As far as I understand, the 'file' field is like any other field in form-data

Comment: @runtimeZero check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/893780) to convert `base64Image` to a `Blob` (and subsequently add it to a `FormData` instance). I think that right now, the image is transferred as a regular string, so `multer` thinks it's a simple form field and not a file.

Comment: @robertklep if you can place your comment as a "answer", I can mark it so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file data is being uploaded as a Base64 string, which suggests that it's not being uploaded as a proper `File` form data field. That's why `multer` treats it as a regular field, and doesn't attempt to save it to a file.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/5100158#5100158), some client side code is presented to handle data-URI strings (like `base64Image`) to the right format to upload to the server.